# How change numbering in remark in this way?

Tags: numbering, environments

I am writing a article on mathematics using Latex. I want to number my theorems and remarks in the following way:

```
Section 1
Theorem 1.1
Remark 1.1.1
Remark 1.1.2
Theorem 1.2
Remrak 1.2.1
...
```

I have written the following code :

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
```

How can I change the codes to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: `\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}[thm]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `rmk` share a counter with `thm`.

Instead you want it to have its own counter which is reset by `thm`, just as `thm` is reset by `section` so use the form you used for `thm`:

`\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}[thm]`